# apache poi powerpoint make nested table

Tags: apache-poi

I want to format my text nicely inside the table cell. I am thinking of a table, is it possible doing nested table? or adding textbox inside the table cell?

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide()
XSLFTable table = slide.createTable();
XSLFTableRow tr = table.addRow();

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    XSLFTableCell cell = tr.addCell();
    ///cell.insert(innertable)
    or
    ///cell.insertextbox(textbox)
```

something like:

```
----------------------------------------
column1 | column 2            | column 3
----------------------------------------
AAAA    | ProductName         |
        | ------------------- |
        | | id | description| |
        | |    |            | |
        | ------------------- |
```

Comment: Have you tried using PowerPoint GUI? If so you would have seen, that nested tables are not possible. Only merging table cells would be possible. But this will be very complicated to manage for a big amount of data.